# Client can not see updated data when connects to server application

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, websocket, socket.io

I'm using node.js to read data from socket on my web application (server). I receive data and make some changes on webpage (ex: change the color of polyline) but when a client after that changes connects, cannot see the changed color unless a new data is sent to server! So how client can see the previous changes which were on server?

here is my code

**app.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express'),
    app = module.exports.app = express();

var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);  //pass a http.Server instance
server.listen(3000);  //listen on port 80

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//var app = require('http').createServer(handler);
//var io = require('socket.io').listen(app);
var fs = require('fs');

var mySocket = 0;

//app.listen(3000); //Which port are we going to listen to?

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html', //Load and display outputs to the index.html file
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  console.log('Webpage connected'); //Confirmation that the socket has connection to the webpage
  mySocket = socket;
});

//UDP server on 41181
var dgram = require("dgram");
var server = dgram.createSocket("udp4");

server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
  console.log("Broadcasting Message: " + msg); //Display the message coming from the terminal to the command line for debugging
  if (mySocket != 0) {
     mySocket.emit('field', "" + msg);
     mySocket.broadcast.emit('field', "" + msg); //Display the message from the terminal to the webpage
  }
});

server.on("listening", function () {
  var address = server.address(); //IPAddress of the server
  console.log("UDP server listening to " + address.address + ":" + address.port);
});

server.bind(41181);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
            <script>
            var socket = io.connect('http://192.168.1.14:3000');
            socket.on('field', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                $("#field").html(data);

                switch(data) 
                {
                    case "1": 
                    $("#path1").css("stroke", "red");
                    $("#progress1").css("backgroundColor", "red");
                    break;

                }



            });
        </script>
<body>
<polyline id="path1" points="600,270 560,262 460,270 440,300" style="fill:none;stroke:green;stroke-width:3" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On connection you have to emit already existing changes to socket client.

```
var myMessage;
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('Webpage connected'); //Confirmation that the socket has connection to the webpage
    mySocket = socket;

    mySocket.emit('field', "" + myMessage); // <<-- like this
    server.on("message", function (msg, rinfo) {
      console.log("Broadcasting Message: " + msg); //Display the message coming from the terminal to the command line for debugging
      if (mySocket != 0) {
        myMessage = msg;
        mySocket.emit('field', "" + msg);
        mySocket.broadcast.emit('field', "" + msg); //Display the message from the terminal to the webpage
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: again it didn't worked.. when the color is changed after that i connect to page as a client but it see the unchanged page.

Comment: I just edited the code a little, you may have to use a variable to keep track of user changes and you have to send it to client on connection.

Comment: thanks but could you please write the code. cause I'm new to it. I tried many times but I got error. please update it on your answer.